# Fetching all possible product parameters from an eshop XML file

Tags: php, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a probably very simple issue with arrays in PHP which I can't seem to figure out even with the help of extensive internet searching.

I'm trying to parse an XML file export from a supplier's eshop for my own dropshipping business. Specifically, I'm trying to organize all possible product parameters into a single, readable array that could be inserted into my database and being linked to from the individual products. The source XML looks like this:

```
<SHOPITEM>
    <ID>...</ID>
    <PRODUCT>...</PRODUCT>
    <PRICE>...</PRICE>    

    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Param name 1</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>Param value 1</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    <PARAM>
        <PARAM_NAME>Param name 2</PARAM_NAME>
        <VAL>Param value 1</VAL>
    </PARAM>
    ...
    <PARAM></PARAM>
    <PARAM></PARAM>
</SHOPITEM>
...
<SHOPITEM></SHOPITEM>
...
```

Every item can have multiple parameters, each with a single value. I am trying to make a multi-dimensional array with all possible parameters including all possible values of those like this:

```
Array
(
    [Parameter1] => Array
        (
        [0] => Value for Parameter1
        [1] => Value for Parameter1
        [2] => Value for Parameter1
        )
    [Parameter2] => Array
        (
        [0] => Value for Parameter2
        [1] => Value for Parameter2
        [2] => Value for Parameter2
        )
)
```

The PHP code works very well in my mind, but it keeps returning empty level 2 arrays:

EDIT: Thanks to Herbert's answer I clarified the code a little. Now the problem seems to be that the values in the nested array (`$array[$param_name]`) always get REPLACED at index 0, not added to the array. I am baffled by this behavior.

```
$file = simplexml_load_file("sourceFile.xml");

$array = array();

foreach ($file->SHOPITEM as $shopitem) {
    foreach ($shopitem->PARAM as $param) {
        $param_name = (string)$param->PARAM_NAME;
        $param_val  = (string)$param->VAL;

        if(!in_array($param_name, $array)) {
            $array[$param_name] = array();
        }

        if(!in_array($param_val, $array[$param_name])) {

            array_push($array[$param_name], $param_val);
            //same as: $array[$param_name][] = $param_val;
    }
}
```

Any insight would be warmly welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The reason values were not added was because both actions were in a single loop - something about global and local variables probably. This is the code that works:

```
$file = simplexml_load_file("ExportZbozi.xml");

$array = array();

foreach ($file->SHOPITEM as $shopitem) {
    foreach ($shopitem->PARAM as $param) {
        $param_name = (string)$param->PARAM_NAME;

        if(!in_array($param_name, $array)) {
            $array[$param_name] = array();
        }
    }
}

foreach ($file->SHOPITEM as $shopitem) {
    foreach ($shopitem->PARAM as $param) {
        $param_name = (string)$param->PARAM_NAME;
        $param_val  = (string)$param->VAL;

        if(!in_array($param_val, $array[$param_name])) {
            $array[$param_name][] = $param_val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: technically you only need one loop. And no, this was not about local and global variables (all in the same scope here), but just doing some mistake. you somehow managed it by separating that one loop into two loops to not make that same mistake again and so it now works.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're not updating the `$array` variable with `$params_array`.

Try this:

```
$file = simplexml_load_file("sourceFile.xml");

$array = array();

foreach ($file->SHOPITEM as $shopitem) {
    foreach ($shopitem->PARAM as $param) {
        $param_name = (string)$param->PARAM_NAME;
        $param_val  = (string)$param->VAL;

        if(!in_array($param_name, $array)) {
            $array[$param_name] = array();
        }

        $params_array = $array[$param_name];

        if(!in_array($param_val, $params_array)) {
            $params_array[] = $param_val;
        }

        $array[$param_name] = $params_array;  // update the main array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses the array as a map so that each value does only exist once because the value is used as key as well. This simplifies your task a lot:

```
$array = array();

foreach ($file->SHOPITEM as $shopitem)
{
    foreach ($shopitem->PARAM as $param) 
    {
        $name = (string)$param->PARAM_NAME;
        $val  = (string)$param->VAL;

        $array[$name][$value] = 1;
    }
}
```

If you want to change that afterwards, use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) on the second level/inner value arrays.